# What cloud service should we use for a Parse Server

Tags: parse-server

We have 2 social iOS/Android apps of 100 concurrent users each and we can afford about $500/month in total... Each app should use 1-2 application servers and 1 db server.

I now have 1 application server and 1 db server for each app, both of 4-vcpus and 4GB RAM.

We are currently on Azure, but our 1-year is ending... I'm thinking of Heroku, DigitalOcean, back4app and Syncano. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a lot of users and you don't want to do a lot of work, Heroku is your best option.

However, if you want to have more control over your server, I think using [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/) is a good choice to run your server with a parse server image on your cloud platform of your choice. They support all major clouds.